# IntelliJ and git, how to ignore white space changes from IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Using `git`, we can `git diff --check`, which would

> -- warn if changes introduce trailing whitespace or space/tab indents

**Can I configure `IntelliJ` to only detect change if it does not begin and end with whitespace modifications? (like formatting)**

In other words, when i click this icon, i only want to see changes made to my code, excluding formatting and other white space changes

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `detect change`? Highlight in gutter and file status color?

Comment: I would like for IDEA to ignore any change not affecting content (for the purposes of `git commit`).

Comment: Like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75868?

Comment: Basically the issue is this: When committing changes i'd like to describe them sufficiently. "Formatting" is nice, but really, i'd like  to commit changes with more substance. If nothing else, i'd like to detect that formatting was the only change, or not

Comment: IMO, IDEA-75868 should cover this case. If not, submit a new request.

Comment: The standards (e.g. PEP8) have some focus on whitespace (including trailing). I can't see why it should be ignored. Simply make sure to follow the standard, and you shouldn't have a problem!

Answer (score 2):

As noted above:

> IMO, IDEA-75868 should cover this case. If not, submit a new request.

This feature is not yet available, but is being tracked.

**References**

- [IDEA-75868 commit diff view: provide ignore whitespace options](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75868)

Comment: This feature would be better complemented with the ability to ignore whitespace on a merge.  Please up vote this request  IDEA-107714.    https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107714